# Why is this "if" a "dead code"?

Tags: java

I have the following code :

```
/** Width of each brick in pixels */
    private static final int BRICK_WIDTH = 11; 

/** Width of each brick in pixels */
    private static final int BRICK_HEIGHT = 12;

/** Number of bricks in the base of the pyramid */
    private static final int BRICKS_IN_BASE = 14;

public void run () {

    int LowerLeftSide;
    if (BRICK_WIDTH / 2 == 0)
    {
         LowerLeftSide = ((getWidth()/2) - (BRICK_WIDTH*(BRICKS_IN_BASE/2)));
    }else 
         LowerLeftSide = ((getWidth()/2) - (BRICK_WIDTH*(BRICKS_IN_BASE/2-1)));
```

eclipse marks the whole `if` as dead code. I initialize the value at the very beginning of the run method.

Thanks.

Comment: Please include the declaration and initialization for `BRICK_WIDTH`

Comment: I think, you should give wider context. More code.

Comment: Is that first curly brace a typo? Because if not, I'm betting that's why.

Comment: You should put `BRICK_WIDTH / 2` in parentheses. Or loose the `/ 2` completely, you don't need it.

Comment: There's no number you can divide by 2 to get 0 unless it's 0!

Comment: @BobFlannigon This is `Java`. `1/2` for example is 0 in `int` calculations.

Comment: asking for a solution and posting unclear and incomplete ques - edit your ques

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks like `BRICK_WIDTH` is a constant, thus `BRICK_WIDTH/2` is known at compile time and the eclipse knows which path will be taken, so the other one is dead code.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Is there a way to circumvent because the program has to be independent of the specific value of BRICK_WIDTH.

Comment: Circumvent what? `BRICK_WIDTH` will never change during execution. If you want `BRICK_WIDTH` to be evaluated during runtime you must not declare it as `static final`.

Comment: @MindaugasBernatavičius If you just want to suppress the warning, try putting `@SuppressWarnings("deadCode")` on the line before it? (Suggested by [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085520/how-do-i-suppress-eclipse-3-5s-warnings-of-dead-code).)

Comment: Understood. The the "if" conditional will not solve the problem I have. I will try to find another way.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

As you are using capitals for `BRICK_WIDTH` I assume you defined it as a constant (`final`)? Then, unless `BRICK_WIDTH == 0` (or 1 and maybe -1 assuming it's an `int`), `BRICK_WIDTH / 2` will never be 0. Hence the code under if will never be reached.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Totally mispoke in my answer.

What is the value of `BRICK_WIDTH`? If it's zero, then that well always execute, and it will never go into the `else`.

Comment: that's not true. if [BRICK_WIDTH] is zero, one would go in the [if] part and never in the else part. so else would be dead code.

Comment: `BRICK_WIDTH` doesn't have to be `0` to make `BRICK_WIDTH / 2 == 0`! `1/2` is evaluated to `0` too.

Answer (score 0):

@oalsing you are right but in case of BRICK_WIDTH = 1, eclipse will say else block is dead code and comparing identical expression because values are hard coded.

Answer (score 0):

your IDE calls a code dead code when the condition you provide for the loop is never going to be true , thus the program never gets to use the code within the condition block .

Thus it is illogical to write some code line which is syntactically correct but is never going to be used . That is why as a convention its called a DEAD CODE .

you may encounter situations like

```
while(false){}
if(false){}
```

in your case

```
private static final int BRICK_WIDTH = 11;
if (BRICK_WIDTH / 2 == 0){}
```

since your variable is defined final thus compiler knows it will never change its value , thus the condition is never going to be true . So following the convention , its called a dead code .

Answer (score -1):

```
{   
int LowerLeftSide;
if ((BRICK_WIDTH / 2) == 0) {
     LowerLeftSide = ((getWidth()/2) - (BRICK_WIDTH*(BRICKS_IN_BASE/2)));
} else {
     LowerLeftSide = ((getWidth()/2) - (BRICK_WIDTH*(BRICKS_IN_BASE/2-1)));
}
```

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you're trying to get at here. Please explain your answer.

Answer (score -1):

The only time you will enter if, (I assume BRICK_WIDTH is a positivte integer) is when BRICK_WIDTH = 1;

Since a value / 2 never is 0, but in java 1/2 = 0, due to it's way of handling integers.

EDIT: I dont know why it says it's dead code, but this is a general thought.

Comment: `1/2 == 0` is not Java specific, and ... this doesn't answer the question.